# Windows form changes size on Visual Studio running via Parallels Desktop

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, screen-resolution, parallels

I am trying to create an app in Visual Studio in Windows 8.1. However, this is running on Mac via Parallels Desktop.

When I run the app it appears as it is coded, maximized at startup. See image 1. However when I press the Open button, the resolution of the app changes. See image 2.

How do I stop this from happening?

The code for the button doesn't seem to change the resolution. See image 3.[image]

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Please show us your Code in OpenFIle()

Comment: I have added the screenshot of the relevant code.

Comment: Do you have the same Issue if you add a Button which does nothing? It looks like your code does nothing UI relevant things...

Comment: Just tested it. If there a button which does nothing and is pressed, the resolution does not change.

Comment: Ok... Seems like your code does UI relevant things... Try to use the Debugger to Step through every Line of Code until you find the Line which does Change the Window state.

Comment: Yes you're right. It appears ObjectOleDbConnection.Open(); seems to change the resolution.

Comment: This goes in a direction which i don't know anymore... As Workaround you should be able to change the Window State after the Open Method.